# Secure AJAX request to URI

Tags: php, ajax, security, restful-url

I know there have been lots of question about AJAX security. I've searched and read but am still unclear as to what the best approach is.

I have a very specific senario:

I have an application that is build on top a PHP MVC framework. I've turned presentation elements such as a "navigation menu" modular. The navigation menu module has a controller (sever side). The controller uses a model to retrieving data from the database and then it responds with a php echo of the data. I can make the http request to the controller using AJAX because the controller is routed to by a URI. I believe this is call a RESTful API. When the user clicks a link in the navigation menu a static content area is update with the data that was retrieved from the AJAX request. Lets say that I Make a different action in the same controller that is capable of writing data to the database. Having a publicly available URI that allows writing to the database is obviously bad. How does one secure the URI interface so that AJAX can retrieve and write data, but those individuals with malicious intent can do harm?

Comment: "I know there have been lots of question about AJAX security." --- and they all make no sense. There is **nothing** (seriously, nothing at all) special in AJAX - it's a regular HTTP request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must treat an ajax request as you treat a get request or post request.
In other words never trust the user. You have server side control, ajax is client side so never trust "CLIENT SIDE" that makes a request(check the data, if data is ok then return a response if not return another response).

Answer (score 0):

Controller is able to write to database:

There is no true way to secure an public URI interface so that it is only able to be accessed by the part of your application that exists on the client side. The idea is then to not make the interface so public, meaning it cannot be accessed by everyone! If a URI were to point to a “controller” (MVC architecture) and in turn the controller has access to manipulate a critical database, you best make it so the client who sends the request to the controller must “Authenticate”. This concept is true whether the http requests are coming from a web form or Ajax. Typically before Authentication credentials are transmitted using https (http + SSL) to keep a “Man In The Middle” from seeing the credentials.

Controller is able to read from the database:

When a read request is made you can simply return the data, or if its sensitive data require an authenticated client.

The “Navigation menu module” should only be edited by an administrator, so authentication is a must. However, any web surfer who views a page containing the module should not have to authenticate to use the navigation, that would be silly.

Answer (score 0):

The main rule is to validate all inputs - check all data coming in and clear from unwanted chars.

Also, it all depends if You allow user change Your DB without loging in or not. Logged users are easier to verify and You always can put on serwer - side checking scripts - if current user is allowed to do this operation.

Things are harder when You allow annonymous user to write to Your DB. Then, its good to operate mainly on ID`s and if You allow user to insert data from inputs - filter all from unwanted things. The good way of doing it is to create whitelists of chars You approve and cut everything else.

You have to remember, that Ajax is nothing else but sending POST request to url - and You should do the same protection as with standard forms. Also good practice is to add a token to Your send data - wich You can verify by server side.